# How to determine how Linux sees Windows drives

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm aware that the Windows `C:\` drive appears in the Windows Subsystem for Linux as `/mnt/c`.  However, in bash Git hook scripts the `C:\` drive appears as `/c`, not `/mnt/c`.

Is there any way from within a bash script to determine how the `C:\` drive should be referenced?  In other words, is there any way to determine whether a path should be built up using `/mnt/c` or `/c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git) realm:

Here the POSIX functionalities are provided by [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) shared dynamic library (aka. DLL) and `/bin/git.exe` is cross-compiled (PE) for that environment. The mount point in this environment, is [same as UNIX systems](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table), is configured by `/etc/fstab`. Here is the sample:

```
none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,noacl,user 0 0
```

So, the Windows drives are monted in `/` (root) folder. For example, `C:\` becomes `/c`. This is default option. Users can change it to desired value.

#### Windows Subsystem for Linux realm:

Here WSL executes real [ELF64 binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) which are forked from `/init`. The mount points are managed by that init binary and Lx Subsystem Session Manager Service (LxssManager). By default, all Windows partitions are mounted in `/mnt` folder. Beginning with Insider Build 17093, the mount points can be configured with `/etc/wsl.conf` file. Read [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/) carefully for further information. Here is an sample:

```ini
[automount]
enabled = true
mountFsTab = true
root = /
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
```

In short, this file:

- `enabled`: Automatically mount Windows drives.
- `mountFsTab`: Automatically mount user configured drives from `/etc/fstab` file.
- `root`: Directory where Windows drives will be mounted.
- `options`: Mount options for Windows drives. These are same as `mount -o` command.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit of a non-starter as it makes incorrect assumptions.  For a start Windows drives can be mounted in different ways - as local disks, as SMB mounts, as NFS mounts spring to mind.

/mnt/c may be applicable your distro, but it's not particularly common and not the case in Ubuntu type distros, which use /media?deviceid/ - where.deviceid is not a drive letter.

Similarly, "C" drive is fairly arbitrary - Linux does have a structure for drives - so if it's a local hard drive you can probably find a way to scan /dev/sd*? for NTFS partitions and see if they are mounted. This is not a good general solution as it  makes lots of assumptions which are often likely to be incorrect - you might be better off prompting for a path.

Another (error prone) way might be to assume the disk is mounted and then use `df` and parse each (non shm) system for windows/