# Configure Cmder/ConEmu to correctly convert paths (remove /mnt/ prefix)?

Tags: windows-10, conemu, git-bash, cmder

Across multiple installs of Cmder I have had this issue.

When running Git Bash the drives are [mounted to `/`](https://superuser.com/a/1444535/1617310), but when pasting windows paths into the console it converts as if they are mounted in `/mnt/`. So pasting in "C:\Users" becomes "/mnt/c/Users" which doesn't exist

Digging around in the settings seems to indicate it's related to a feature called "Paste(8): paste path from clipboard converted to POSIX style". But it's unclear how I can change this to work with mounts on `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally discovered that you can remap this using [task switch arguments](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html). However although it says that it's possible to unset it I could not figure out a method. Setting to `m:""`, `m:''`, `m:` and `m:/` all failed in different interesting ways.

My hacky workaround, in Task commands section add the option to override the prefix but set it to `/.`, which will give you paths starting with `/./` instead of `/`, but works fine.

My task then becomes `-new_console:m:/. "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\bash.exe" --login -i`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by pushing the -new_console:m:"" at then end (append the parameter) of the command to trigger bash

[image]